# Eliminating more than one succeeding instance of a string down cells in R

Tags: r, string, dataframe, substr

I am relatively new to R. I have a dataframe of 5 million observations and 1 variable that looks something like this:

`PMID- 28524368
PMID- 28504342
PMID- 28501042
RN - 4964P6T9RB (Aldosterone)
RN - EC 3.4.23.15 (Renin)
RN - RWP5GA015D (Potassium)
MH - Adrenal Cortex Neoplasms/*diagnostic imaging/pathology/surgery
MH - Adrenocortical Adenoma/*diagnostic imaging/pathology/surgery
MH - Aldosterone/blood
MH - Humans
PMID- 28523858
PMID- 28517030
PMID- 28513869
MH - Hyperaldosteronism/*complications
MH - Hypertension/*etiology
MH - Male
MH - Middle Aged
MH - Potassium/blood
PMID- 28494487
PMID- 28493475
MH - Renin/blood
MH - Tomography, X-Ray Computed`

However, I only want there to be 1 PMID in succession, and that too, the first one - the rest of the PMIDs should be deleted, resulting in a dataframe that looks like:

`PMID- 28524368
RN - 4964P6T9RB (Aldosterone)
RN - EC 3.4.23.15 (Renin)
RN - RWP5GA015D (Potassium)
MH - Adrenal Cortex Neoplasms/*diagnostic imaging/pathology/surgery
MH - Adrenocortical Adenoma/*diagnostic imaging/pathology/surgery
MH - Aldosterone/blood
MH - Humans
PMID- 28523858
MH - Hyperaldosteronism/*complications
MH - Hypertension/*etiology
MH - Male
MH - Middle Aged
MH - Potassium/blood
PMID- 28494487
MH - Renin/blood
MH - Tomography, X-Ray Computed`

Please advise. I tried using:

```
# remove excessive PMIDs
for (i in nrow(original_reduced))
{
  if (substr(original_reduced[i, 1], 1, 4) == "PMID")
  {
    if (substr(original_reduced[i+1, 1], 1, 4) == "PMID" && i != nrow(original_reduced)) # if next row is also PMID
    {
      original_reduced <- original_reduced[-c(i+1), ] # delete entry after
    }
  }
}
```

but I got this error:

`Error in if (substr(original_reduced[i + 1, 1], 1, 4) == "PMID") { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed`

even though I have no NAs in my dataframe.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working solution.  See comments for an explanation of the code

```
 df<-structure(list(V1 = c("PMID- 28524368", "PMID- 28504342", "PMID- 28501042", 
"RN - 4964P6T9RB (Aldosterone)", "RN - EC 3.4.23.15 (Renin)", 
"RN - RWP5GA015D (Potassium)", "MH - Adrenal Cortex Neoplasms/*diagnostic imaging/pathology/surgery", 
"MH - Adrenocortical Adenoma/*diagnostic imaging/pathology/surgery", 
"MH - Aldosterone/blood", "MH - Humans", "PMID- 28523858", "PMID- 28517030", 
"PMID- 28513869", "MH - Hyperaldosteronism/*complications", "MH - Hypertension/*etiology", 
"MH - Male", "MH - Middle Aged", "MH - Potassium/blood", "PMID- 28494487", 
"PMID- 28493475", "MH - Renin/blood", "MH - Tomography, X-Ray Computed"
)), .Names = "V1", row.names = c(NA, -22L), class = "data.frame")

library(dplyr)

#Add flag for PMID rows
   df$pmid<-grepl("^PMID", df$V1)
#find rows of where n == n+1
   matches<-df$pmid==lag(df$pmid)
#find rows equal to previous row and is a PMID row
   toremove<-which(matches==TRUE & df$pmid==TRUE)
#remove rows
   df<-df[-toremove,]
   df$pmid<-NULL  #remove added column
```

Comment: your code deleted all of the PMIDs...I'm assuming the `lag` function is not working as it should...seems very promising, however

Comment: Was the dplyr library loaded?  This will not work if the base package's lag function is used.

Comment: I fixed it by adding n = 1 to your `lag` function...thank you!!!  `matches <-df$pmid == lag(df$pmid, n = 1)`. also thank you greatly for your comments - as a beginner, they really helped me!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
df%>%mutate(number=sequence(rle(name)[['lengths']]))%>%filter((number==1 & grepl('PMID',number))|!grepl('PMID',name))%>%select(name)
```